# 2D MATRIX QUERY

Tags: c++, matrix

can someone help me with what this segment of code means?

```
int m = matrix.size(), n = m ? matrix[0].size() : 0, r = 0, c = n - 1;
```

Comment: Two int initializations on one line and this https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/comma-and-conditional-operators/  and look for conditional operator. However in my opinion the developer that wrote this didn't really have the intention to write readable/maintainable code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The comma operator is not present in the shown code - the commas are just separating declarations.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes I misread a bit on the first try ;) Had to write it out myself to see there where only initializations (one using a ternary operation). Funny how much influence "convention" has on being able to read code fast.

Answer (score 2):

Easier to read version of the same code :

```
int m = matrix.size(); // get number of rows
int n = m ? matrix[0].size() : 0; // if there are columns, then n becomes the number of columns, zero otherwise
int r = 0;
int c = n - 1;
```